# Control video playback when mouse in defined zone

Tags: javascript, video, position, mouse

I'm trying to control video playback depending on where my mouse is on screen.
I've split the width of the window into 3 areas - left, centre and right. This works fine so far.
When the mouse is in the 'left' I want to specify to jump to a certain time, same for centre and right.
The issue I'm having is that every time the mouse moves the video playback restarts, I want it to change only when it changes from 'left' to 'right' or 'centre'. I've made a current_pos and new_pos variable but can't figure out how to update them properly.

Many thanks!

PS have left out the video code for now, just trying to get the position working.

```
var viewport_width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var viewport_height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var current_pos;
var new_pos;

function getMousePos(e) {
    return {x:e.clientX,y:e.clientY};
}
document.onmousemove=function(e) {
  
    var mousecoords = getMousePos(e);
  
  //left

  if (mousecoords.x < viewport_width/3){
    
    current_pos = 'left';
 
    
  //centre

  }else if (mousecoords.x > viewport_width/3 && mousecoords.x < viewport_width*.66){
    current_pos = 'centre';

  //right 

  }else {
    current_pos = 'right';
  }
    
    console.log(current_pos);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether `current_pos` has been changed every time you attempt to change it.

```
var viewport_width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var viewport_height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var current_pos;

function getMousePos(e) {
  return {
    x: e.clientX,
    y: e.clientY
  };
}
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
  var mousecoords = getMousePos(e);

  //left
  if (mousecoords.x < viewport_width / 3) {
    if(current_pos != 'left') {
      current_pos = 'left';
      // Play your video from the desired point
    }
  //centre
  } else if (mousecoords.x > viewport_width / 3 && mousecoords.x < viewport_width * .66) {
    if(current_pos != 'centre') {
      current_pos = 'centre';
      // Play your video from the desired point
    }
  //right 
  } else {
    if(current_pos != 'right') {
      current_pos = 'right';
      // Play your video from the desired point
    }
  }
  console.log(current_pos);
};
```

Comment: Thank you Wais. This is perfect, I was tying myself up in mental knots with this. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to help! More glad to see you putting on that green tick ;)